# SQL Grouping and max value

Tags: sql

Need a bit of help here. I'm trying to only return the record with the largest "rev" for each serial number, here's my sample code:

```
SELECT
    serial,
    MAX(rev) max_rev,
    code
FROM
    Table1
GROUP BY
    serial, code
```

Here's what I am getting. Note that I only want each serial number record with the max rev (s/n 454 max rev 5 code RT and s/n 655 max rev 8 code KV in this case):

```
serial    max_rev   code
------------------------    
454       4         SV
454       5         RT
655       7         JT
655       8         KV
```

Comment: [Why should I "tag my RDBMS"?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/why-should-i-tag-my-rdbms) - please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't think aggregation.  Think filtering -- you want entire rows is the difference.

So:

```
select t.*
from table1 t
where t.rev = (select max(t2.rev)
               from table1 t2
               where t2.serial = t.serial
              );
```

Comment: this is helpful, seems like it works for my problem, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me.

```
select table1.*
from table1
inner join (select serial, max(rev) as 'max_rev'
            from table1
            group by serial) t1 on t1.serial = table1.serial and t1.max_rev = table1.rev
```